# Doesn't this script create the same table every time it's run?

Tags: mysql

Recently I've been trying to work with databases to advance my website functionality. I keep seeing different ways to create tables; one of them seems to be to create your table through code.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE `phone` (
    `id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `country` DECIMAL(5,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `area` DECIMAL(5,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `number` DECIMAL(8,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `extension` DECIMAL(5,0) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm confused about this. If this is in your PHP code, then every time that script is run wouldn't it try to create this same table over and over? Or does this only work if the table does not already exist?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html `CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name`

Comment: *"or does this only work if the table DOES NOT exist?"* -  Yes, but that will throw an error if you do run it more than once and that a table already exists. Use above syntax ^

Comment: *"Also can anyone point me in the direction on the differences of row types? A page that explains what a mediumint is and decimal and such?"* - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-types.html I mean really, this could have been Google'd and easily avoided this question. 2 seconds on Google "column types mysql".

Answer (score 1):

This is SQL, specifically MySQL not PHP.

As such for information on row types read the manual for MySQL.  It is well documented.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html

And there is a way to have that table be created `IF NOT EXISTS`.  But typically you will not be trying to automate thigns like table creation from your code.  I'd suggest getting an IDE for your database design.  There is a free [MySQL GUI Tools / Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html) provided by Sun.

Comment: Then where do you insert this code? That is what I am lost about mostly. I figured it had to be PHP, but again that's newbie confusion.

Comment: Into a SQL command line or tab in a GUI tool like MySQL workbench.

Comment: Suppose I mean 'Oracle' and not 'Sun'... senior moment, sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will try to create the table every time; and, when the table already exists, it will fail.

Three ways to get around this:

- Add an `IF NOT EXISTS` modifier: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS phone (...)`.

  This will make MySQL silently skip the statement when the table already exists.
- Change the surrounding PHP¹ code so that it only runs the `CREATE TABLE` statement if it somehow detects that the table is missing. (For instance, if a `SELECT` or `INSERT` fails.)
- Provide a separate script for setting up the database, which is run only once, by the person installing whatever it is that uses the database. The same script could also do other one-off tasks, such as inserting sample data and generating random tokens.

  (If run again, it might check whether the necessary tables exist, and attempt to repair or upgrade them if necessary.)

¹ Other server-side scripting languages are available.